# How can I colour/paint my object?

Tags: modeling, texture-painting

Very very very new to blender but is it possible to colour different parts of an object? (.obj import from fusion). if so; how do I change the colour of different areas of my object? [image: Text]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)

Comment: Kind of? I don't know how to pick the bits that I actually want

Comment: The author specifically mentions painting in the title as well, which is a whole different category from assigning materials to different parts of a mesh. For painting, specifically, one will need to research UV editing and texture painting.

Comment: Yes, the word "paint" is in the title. Sorry, if I missed that but in the text of the question there only the verbs  "to colour" and "to change the colour" which means to change colour. It's misleading and if this question is really about texture painting then it should be edited and clarified.

Comment: No need to apologize. I'm commenting for benefit of informing the author, not for the sake of criticizing those kind enough to provide answers.

Answer (score 0):

Select your object, and go to the shading tab. Press Shift>A and then click Texture>Image Texture. Press new on the image texture node and put the resolution. (It's 1K by default, so click and drag down on the dimension values and multiply by 2,3,4,5 however high res you want it.) Once that is done, connect the dot in front of the clour input in the image texture node into the dot before the Base Colour input of the Principled BSDF node (You can connect the dots by clicking on one and then dragging it on top of the other dot you need to connect). Once that is done, switch to the Texture Paint tab. In texture paint you can press Alt>S and specify a file folder to save your image. If you don't do that and close blender even after saving the .blend file, your pianting will be lost. Make sure to paint directly on to your mesh. To paint just select a colour and start painting. The rest of the features can be learned by tutorials on platforms like YouTube.

Note: I reccomend that you watch a UV-Unwrapping tutorial on YouTube and UV Unwrap your mesh before this procedure.

Comment: Ah, ok I'll look into it. Thankyou!